# string to DateTime? extending Convert.* or something better

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

hopefully I'm not recreating something already asked a 1000-times, but searching for it is difficult because of the '?'-s.

I want to convert a string in Datetime? in c#.
What is the cleaner way to accomplish that than this:

```
    private static DateTime? toDate(string probDate)
    {
        if (probDate == null) { return null; }
        else { return Convert.ToDateTime(probDate); }
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Harry

Comment: There's no such thing as `string?` in C#, as `string` is a reference type, and therefore already nullable.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) methods (if you are on .Net 3.5+). It is very elegant as well as reusable.

Like so:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime? ToNullableDate(this String dateString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((dateString ?? "").Trim()))
            return null;

        DateTime resultDate;
        if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out resultDate))
            return resultDate;

        return null;
    }
}


public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        string dateString = null;
        DateTime? nullableDate = dateString.ToNullableDate();            
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for! Extending String looks legit, what about Convert?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot extend Convert, since it is a static class. I would stick with extending String.

Answer (score 4):

```
private static DateTime? toDate(string probDate)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(probDate)) {
        DateTime converted;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(probDate, out converted))
        {
            return converted;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It depends. If probDate cannot be converted, what do you want to happen? Should the method return null, or throw an exception?

**Response to comment #1**

Since your method signature was private, I assumed this was just a static helper method for a specific class. If this is something you want to reuse throughout the application, I would create an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? ToDate(this string probDate)
    {
        // same code as above
    }
}
```

You can then execute it like this:

```
string probDate = "1/4/2012";
DateTime? toDate = probDate.ToDate();
```

Comment: if probDate is set, it can be converted by default because its an System set variable. Its less the question of this detail, than where to implement the new function: does it make sense to extent "Convert" or something?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could at least use a conditional:

```
private static DateTime? ToDate(string text)
{
    return text == null ? (DateTime?) null : Convert.ToDateTime(text);
}
```

Personally I'd probably use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the expected format rather than `Convert.ToDateTime`, but that's a different matter.

You haven't really explained what the bigger picture is here - where is the text coming from? Does it *have* an expected format? Do you need to be culture-sensitive? What do you want to happen if the text can't be parsed?

Answer (score 1):

```
static class Program
  {

    //Extension method for string
    public static DateTime? ToNullableDate(this string text)
    {
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)  ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(text);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
      string s = null;
      DateTime? d = s.ToNullableDate();

      s = "1/1/2012";
      d = s.ToNullableDate();
    }  
  }
```